# How to add imageView width/height programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, image-size

How do I change the `width/height` of `UIImageView`. I have a lot of pictures with different `width/height` and I'd like them to show at the size of imageView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    let city = nicosiaPlaces [indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = city
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: city)
    cell?.imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    return cell!
}
```

I want to make this line of code work:

```
cell?.imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
```

Comment: `size` property of `frame` is a `ready only` (only `get`, no `set`) if I remember correctly. So instead, retrieve the `frame`, and recalculate it with keeping the origin and just changing the size with `cell?.imageView?.frame = CGRect(origin: cell?.imageView?.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))`, or `cell?.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: cell?.imageView?.frame.origin.x, y: cell?.imageView?.frame.origin.y, width: 10, height: 10)`

Comment: that didn't worked :(

Comment: Do you want the actual `UIImageView` to resize or do you want the size to be fixed and have the actual images resized within it?

Comment: This looks to be just ac copy of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226153/how-to-resize-the-imageview

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

```
cell?.imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
```

With:

```
cell?.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cell?.imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
cell?.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
```

It looks like you want the `cell` to be optional, but if the above doesn't work try removing the question marks.